# java.lang.String is not valid external type for schema of string

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Given this, seem have done this in the past ok, but...:

```
val arrayStructData2 = Seq(
      Row("James", 2),
      Row("Alex", 3)
    )

 val arrayStructSchema2 = new StructType()
                            .add("names",new StructType()
                                 .add("name", StringType)
                                 .add("extraField", IntegerType)
                                )

val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(arrayStructData2),arrayStructSchema2)
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

I get this:

```
...
Caused by: RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of struct<name:string,extraField:int>
```

Can't see it immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others, as a reminder, needed *Row(Row...* as in:

```
val arrayStructData2 = Seq(
      Row(Row("James", 2)),
      Row(Row("Alex", 3))
    )
```

Not so obvious error imho.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the `DataFrame` with `createDataFrame` you register the schema, but nothing is actually evaluated which is why `df.printSchema` works as expected. When you execute `df.show` the `DataFrame` is evaluated and Spark tries to load the first value you have given it (in this case a String) into a `struct` which results in the `runtimeException` you're seeing. Here is the scaladoc for Spark 3.1.1:

> Creates a DataFrame from a java.util.List containing Rows using the given schema. It is important to make sure that the structure of every Row of the provided List matches the provided schema. Otherwise, there will be runtime exception.

It's telling you that you are trying to force a string into a struct.

Comment: See my answer..